# Circles tangential to the real line

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, power-of-the-point

For any two *distinct* points $a,b$ in the upper half plane, prove that there is a circle passing through $a$ and $b$ that is tangential to the extended real line.

Seems obvious, but how would you go about proving this?

Comment: At least one of the two points must be strictly above the real line. If both lies on the real line, there are no solution. Personally, I'd probably use properties from pencils of circles, but those are non-standard I think?

Comment: @N.Bach: Except if $a = b$. Then the two points can both lie on the real line

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention a and b are distinct points

Comment: The equation of a circle in the upper half plane tangent to the real line is $(x - c)^2 + (y-d)^2 = d^2$ where $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $d \in \mathbb{R}^{+} $. If you were to plug the points $a $ and $b $ into this equation, can you always find a $c $ and $d $ which satisfies the system?

Answer (score 1):

This is a fascinating question.

Here’s how I would argue, using the group of rigid motions of the Poincaré (hyperbolic) plane.

What are the (general) circles tangent to the (extended) real line at $\infty$? They are the horizontal lines $Y=c$, for positive real $c$. I suggest applying a rotation $\rho$ about $a=(x_a,y_a)$ in the hyperbolic plane that brings $b$ to a point $b'$ whose height above the real axis is equal to that of $a$, so that $b'=(x_{b'},y_a)$. Now draw the horizontal line $Y=y_a$, and apply $\rho^{-1}$ to this picture. What happens is that $b'$ rotates back to $b$, $\infty$ rotates (most likely) to a finite point $p=(x_p,0)$ on the real axis, and our horizontal line rotates to the circle through $a$, $p$, and $b$, tangent to the real axis at $p$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to consider the case where both points lie on the real line as having been addressed in the comments. So I can assume that $a$ is not on the real line.

The set of points equidistant from the real line and $a$ forms a parabola, $P$, in the upper half plane. The circle center $P$ must lie on this.

The set of points equidistant from $a$ and $b$ forms a line. $P$ must also lie on this. So $P$ is at the intersection of a line and a parabola, hence is one of at most two points. That seems like a pretty fast route, since it involves solving exactly one quadratic.

If the point $a$ is given by $(2r, 2s)$, then the equation of the parabola is 
$$
(x-2r)^2 + (2s)^2 = 4sy
$$
If the point $b = (2p, 2q)$, then the midpoint of $ab$ is $(p+r, q+s)$, and the parametric equation of the perpendicular bisector of $ab$ is
$$
x(t) = (p+r) + t (s-q) \\
y(t) = (q + s) + t(p-r)
$$
Plugging this in, you get

$$
[p+r + t(s-q) - 2r]^2 + 4s^2 = 4s [q + s + t(p-r)]
$$
That's a quadratic in $t$, which you can solve with the quadratic equation, and then plug the result back into the line equation to get the two circle centers.

Doing the algebra:
\begin{align}
[p-r + t(s-q)]^2 + 4s^2 &= 4s [q + s + t(p-r)]\\
(p-r)^2 + 2t(s-q)(p-r) + t^2 (s-q)^2 &= - 4s^2 +4s(q + s) + t\cdot 4s(p-r)\\
(s-q)^2 t^2 + 2t(s-q)(p-r) -2t\cdot 2s(p-r)+(p-r)^2   &= - 4s^2 +4s(q + s)\\
(s-q)^2 t^2 + 2t(p-r)[(s-q) -2s] +(p-r)^2   &= - 4s^2 +4s(q + s)\\
(s-q)^2 t^2 + 2t(p-r)[-(s+q)] +(p-r)^2   &= - 4s^2 +4s(q + s)\\
(s-q)^2 t^2 - 2t(p-r)(s+q) + (p-r)^2  - 4sq  &= 0\\
(s-q)^2 t^2 - 2t(p-r)(s+q) + (p-r)^2 -  4sq  &= 0\\
(s-q)^2 t^2 - 2t(p-r)(s+q) + (p-r)^2 - 4sq  &= 0
\end{align}
That sure *looks* as if there ought to be more $s-q$ terms, and not $s+q$ or $4sq$, but who knows? Anyhow, it's a general guide to how to solve this.

Actually, on reflection, it looks pretty good to me. For if the points $a$ and $b$ have the same $y$-coordinate, then $s-q = 0$, and the quadratic becomes linear...which makes some sense to me --- I can only visualize one circle that passes through both points and is tangent to the $x$-axis. On the other hand, if the $x$-coordinates are the same, then the coefficient of $t$ becomes $0$, and the two roots are negatives of one another, corresponding to the reflection (about a vertical axis) symmetry in the situation. So: except in the $s = q$ case, we get
\begin{align}
t &= \frac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}}{2A}\\
 &= \frac{2(p-r)(s+q) \pm \sqrt{4(p-r)^2(s+q)^2 + 4(s-q)^2 4sq}}{2(s-q)^2}\\
 &= \frac{(p-r)(s+q) \pm \sqrt{(p-r)^2(s+q)^2 + 4(s-q)^2 sq}}{(s-q)^2}\\\end{align}
and then, with these $t$-values, we have
$$
x = (p+r) + t (s-q) \\
y = (q + s) + t(p-r)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $A=a$ and $B=b$.

Suppose line $AB$ cuts real line $\ell$ at $P$ and draw arbitrary circle $C$ through $A$ and $B$. Now draw a tangent from $P$ to $C$ and let it touch $C$ at $E$. Then draw a circle with center at $P$ and radius $PE$. This circle cuts $\ell$ at $D_1$ and $D_2$. Now let perpendicular bisector of $AB$ cuts line $d_i$ which is perpendicular to $\ell$ and goes through $D_i$ at $S_i$. You get the center(s) of circle(s) you seek for.

Proof that this construction is OK. Observe the power of the point of $P$ with respect to the given circles ($P$ is radical center).